# How to create a bar or column chart inside a table cell of each row

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, echarts, plotly.js, react-google-charts

I need to create a bar or column chart inside a table cell of each row.

here is my json

```
[
  {
    "Chocolate": [
      {
        "kisses": [
          {
            "2022": {
              "jan": 2000,
              "feb": 1200,
              "mar": 7000
            }
          },
          {
            "2021": {
              "jan": 2000,
              "feb": 1200,
              "mar": 7000
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "kitkat": [
          {
            "2022": {
              "jan": 1000,
              "feb": 3200,
              "mar": 4500
            }
          },
          {
            "2021": {
              "jan": 2000,
              "feb": 200,
              "mar": 7030
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Drinks": [
      {
        "Coco cola": [
          {
            "2022": {
              "jan": 2000,
              "feb": 1200,
              "mar": 7000
            }
          },
          {
            "2021": {
              "jan": 2200,
              "feb": 1200,
              "mar": 7100
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Pepsi": [
          {
            "2022": {
              "jan": 1000,
              "feb": 3200,
              "mar": 4500
            }
          },
          {
            "2021": {
              "jan": 4550,
              "feb": 2100,
              "mar": 3430
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need column chart inside a cell

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H973g.png)

I found a googlecharts and tried but not able to achieve my requirement.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Chart');
  data.addRows([
    ['Choclate', {v: 10000, f: 'Kisses'}, null],
    ['Drinks', {v: 12500, f: 'Pepsi'}, null],
    ['Food', {v: 7000, f: 'Pizza'}, null]
  ]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    // table body
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(table.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('tbody'), function(tableBody) {
      // table rows
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(tableBody.rows, function(tableRow, rowIndex) {
        // table cells
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(tableRow.cells, function(tableCell, cellIndex) {
          // determine if last cell
          if (cellIndex === (tableRow.cells.length - 1)) {
            // add chart continer
            var chartContainer = tableCell.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
            chartContainer.className = 'chart';

            // build chart data table
            var dataChart = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            dataChart.addColumn('number', 'x');
            dataChart.addColumn('number', 'y');
            for (var i = 0; i <= rowIndex; i++) {
              dataChart.addRow([i, data.getValue(i, 1)]);
            }

            // draw chart
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartContainer);
            chart.draw(dataChart, {
              chartArea: {
                left: 24,
                top: 16,
                right: 24,
                bottom: 16,
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%'
              },
              height: '100%',
              legend: 'none',
              pointSize: 6,
              width: '100%'
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });

  table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '60%', height: '70%'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Even i need to get exact column chart with values i have in my json with pivoted category row as shown in sample image attached.

please suggest someone how can i achieve this.

any chart js is fine like plotly.js or googlecharts or echarts which is javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, code is self-explanatory, comments included.

> Made with [`chart.js`](https://www.chartjs.org)

https://jsfiddle.net/sean7777/j7zy165v/81/

Comment: appreciated but my requirement is different.. i want the graphs inside a table cell. if you run my snippet you get table cell. AM stuck in pivoting category row wise and data to be set in to 3rd column which is chart(like bar or colmun)